# SQLite.swift Create an Array of Column Expressions

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite.swift

Is it possible to create an array of column expressions using SQLite.swift?

```
static let COLUMN_PARTNER_ID = Expression<String>(COLUMN_NAME_PARTNER_ID)
static let COLUMN_COMPANY_ID = Expression<String>(COLUMN_NAME_COMPANY_ID)
static let COLUMN_USER_ID = Expression<String>(COLUMN_NAME_USER_ID)
//this does not work
let columns:Array<Expression<Any>> = [COLUMN_PARTNER_ID, COLUMN_COMPANY_ID,  COLUMN_USER_ID]
```

My goal is to create a base class that handles generic queries.

Comment: did you find any path for generic queries